# nginx in docker fails to talk to localhost

Tags: docker, nginx

The goal is to:

1. Return the same index.html for all requests
2. Except the case when pathname starts from "/api" (e.g. localhost/api/asd) - in that case forward this request to an app running on localhost:8080

I've dealt with the task successfully just running nginx on my ubuntu. But when I try the same in docker container I get 502 for each "/api" request:

> 2019/11/03 14:35:39 [error] 6#6: *22 connect() failed (111: Connection
>   refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.17.0.1, server:
>   127.0.0.1, request: "GET /api/library/source/find?page=0&size=40&q=JTdCJTIycXVlcnklMjIlM0ElMjIlMjIlMkMlMjJwZXJpb2QlMjIlM0ElMjJBTlRJUVVJVFklMjIlMkMlMjJjbGFzc2lmaWNhdGlvbnMlMjIlM0ElNUIlNUQlMkMlMjJ0eXBlcyUyMiUzQSU1QiU1RCU3RA==
>   HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/library/source/find?page=0&size=40&q=JTdCJTIycXVlcnklMjIlM0ElMjIlMjIlMkMlMjJwZXJpb2QlMjIlM0ElMjJBTlRJUVVJVFklMjIlMkMlMjJjbGFzc2lmaWNhdGlvbnMlMjIlM0ElNUIlNUQlMkMlMjJ0eXBlcyUyMiUzQSU1QiU1RCU3RA==",
>   host: "localhost", referrer:
>   "http://localhost/library/period/antiquity"
>   172.17.0.1 - - [03/Nov/2019:14:35:39 +0000] "GET /api/library/source/find?page=0&size=40&q=JTdCJTIycXVlcnklMjIlM0ElMjIlMjIlMkMlMjJwZXJpb2QlMjIlM0ElMjJBTlRJUVVJVFklMjIlMkMlMjJjbGFzc2lmaWNhdGlvbnMlMjIlM0ElNUIlNUQlMkMlMjJ0eXBlcyUyMiUzQSU1QiU1RCU3RA==
>   HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "http://localhost/library/period/antiquity"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.87 Safari/537.36" "-"

'172.17.0.1' looks weird. I use "nginx" image and it has the following in its /etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.2  1a0b306a3a80
```

note '172.17.0.2', not '172.17.0.1'.

Dockerfile and nginx config I'm running may be found here:
https://github.com/ahlinist/tempvs-ui

The image is built and run as:
sudo docker build . -t tempvs-ui
sudo docker run -p 80:80 tempvs-ui

What am I doing wrong? How to make the docker image send requests to localhost:8080?

Comment: first thing nginx is running on 80 then how u server on 8080 in the same container? two process? second thing your nginx config and error does seeme match `http://127.0.0.1:8080/api;`, seems like your `8080` container is down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quick answer**: run docker with additional parameter **network**:

```
docker run -p 80:80 --network=host tempvs-ui
```

The thing is that `localhost` in your docker (host) server and docker container are not the same.
With your current implementation redirect is happened **inside** the docker container. Whereas your target application runs in host machine. That's why there is *Connection refused* error.
Documentation: [docker network](https://docs.docker.com/network), [docker run network param](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#ipc-settings---ipc).

Comment: Thanks! I was missing the fact that localhost inside the container is different from my standalone nginx. The param you suggested works like a charm!